# Help with facebook ios sdk

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk

I've found some tutorials how to connect your app to facebook with facebook ios sdk, but they all use FBSession.h which doesn't exist in the newest version of facebook ios sdk so I don't know how to connect.

Can someone tell me how to connect it with the newest facebook ios sdk, or has some new tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked here? This guide shows you how to use the fb graph api with mobile platforms 
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't tell much, how to customize the message, attachment and stuff

Answer (score 0):

You can add FacebookSDK and deprecated (backwards compatibility) folder into the frameworks group. You can import Facebook.h and it usually has everything u require.